# Flex Panel not shown as disabled

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, photoshop, flex4.5

I am creating a flex panel and a C++ plugin for Photoshop CS5 and CS6 on both Win and Mac. My C++ plugin captures events like layer selection change, document view change etc and dispatch events to flex. In flex I register these events and appropriate functions get called. All this works perfectly.

For example, when user selects another layer from Layer Palette of Photoshop my plugin dispatches an event. This event is captured in flex and a method is called. Inside this method i need to disable my panel, do some processing and then again enable my panel. This works fine on Win XP and on Photoshop CS5 but not on Mac and Win 7.
And if I do a mouse over on my panel when some processing is going on then my panel is displayed as disable otherwise it is displayed as enabled. I am using the following code:

In C++ the layer selection change event is dispatched. In flex it is captured and a function "LayerChange" is called.

```
public function LayerChange(event:CSXSEvent):void
{
  this.enabled = false;
  CursorManager.setBusyCursor();
  //do some processing

  this.enabled = true;
  CursorManager.removeBusyCursor();
}
```

Can someone tell me why the panel is not shown as disabled until and unless mouse moves over the panel?

Thanks